# What's "this" in JavaScript onclick?

Tags: javascript

```
<a onclick="javascript:func(this)" >here</a>
```

What does `this` mean in the script?

Comment: @JMCF125 He managed to be useful anyway. I Googled for how to get the element that was clicked on in an onclick event, and ended up here, where I found the answer.

Comment: what does the javascript: do? why isnt it like this 
`<a onclick="func(this)" >here</a>`

Comment: @J3STER The "javascript:" prefix is incorrect in onclick. You can find the explanation in [Tim Down's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/926170/146513).

Answer (score 115):

In the case you are asking about, `this` represents the HTML DOM element.

So it would be the `<a>` element that was clicked on.

Comment: Can someone link to the spec? Naive look at http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events was fruitless.

Answer (score 38):

It refers to the element in the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) to which the `onclick` attribute belongs:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function func(e) {
  $(e).text('there');
}
</script>
<a onclick="func(this)">here</a>
```

(This example uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).)

Answer (score 25):

The value of event handler attributes such as onclick should just be JavaScript, without any "javascript:" prefix. The javascript: pseudo-protocol is used in a URL, for example:

```
<a href="javascript:func(this)">here</a>
```

You should use the `onclick="func(this)"` form in preference to this though. Also note that in my example above using the javascript: pseudo-protocol "this" will refer to the window object rather than the `<a>` element.

Comment: Interesting downvote, although I suppose strictly speaking this answer only offers advice around the question rather than directly answering the question.

Comment: Yea... you didn't really answer the question :-/ nothing personal!

Comment: @Dave: Fair enough. By the time I wrote this the main question was already answered. My answer should probably have been a comment but I suspect I may not have had enough rep to add a comment at the time. Live and learn.

Comment: Not enough rep at the time? *spits out his wine*

Answer (score 10):

In JavaScript `this` refers to the element containing the action. For example, if you have a function called `hide()`:

```
function hide(element){
   element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Calling `hide` with `this` will hide the element. It returns only the element clicked, even if it is similar to other elements in the DOM.

For example, you may have `this` clicking a number in the HTML below will only hide the bullet point clicked.

```
<ul>
  <li class="bullet" onclick="hide(this);">1</li>
  <li class="bullet" onclick="hide(this);">2</li>
  <li class="bullet" onclick="hide(this);">3</li>
  <li class="bullet" onclick="hide(this);">4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here (this) is a object which contains all features/properties of the dom element.
you can see by

```
console.log(this);
```

This will display all attributes properties of the dom element with hierarchy.
You can manipulate the dom element by this.

Also describe on the below link:-

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Answer (score 5):

keyword *this* in *addEventListener* event

```js
function getValue(o) {
  alert(o.innerHTML);
}

function hide(current) {
  current.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
}

var bullet = document.querySelectorAll(".bullet");

for (var x in bullet) { 
  bullet[x].onclick = function() {
    hide(this);
  };
};
 
/* Using dynamic DOM Event */
document.querySelector("#li").addEventListener("click", function() {
  getValue(this); /* this = document.querySelector("#li") Object */
});
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick="getValue(this);">A</li>
  <li id="li" >B</li>
  <hr />
  <li class="bullet" >1</li>
  <li class="bullet" >2</li>
  <li class="bullet" >3</li>
  <li class="bullet" >4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` referes to the object the `onclick` method belongs to. So inside `func` `this` would be the DOM node of the `a` element and `this.innerText` would be `here`.

Answer (score 3):

When calling a function, the word "this" is a reference to the object that called the function.

In your example, it is a reference to the anchor element. At the other end, the function call then access member variables of the element through the parameter that was passed.