# Confirm box before closing a tab

Tags: javascript, webbrowser-control

I want to have a confirm box when user tries to close the window.

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
    var message = 'Are you sure you want to leave, cause there are some unsaved changes?';
    if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
        evt = window.event;
    }
    if (evt) {
        evt.returnValue = message;
    }

    return message;
}
```

The thing is I want to check a variables value

```js
var sncro = 1;
```

If its value is not equal to one then this confirmation box should be there, else no need to have a confirmation. I'm not able to figure this. Its so silly but I request anybody can have a look on the code.

Comment: Related by for "navigating away" instead of closing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925734/whats-this-in-javascript-onclick Both solved with `onbeforeunload`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that on page load, you are setting up var sncro=1; and when some data changes, you adjust this value. Here is the quick check:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
  if (sncro != 1) {
   var message = 'Are you sure you want to leave, cause there are some unsaved changes?';
   if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
      evt = window.event;
   }
   if (evt ) {
      evt.returnValue = message;
   }
   return message;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Sohnee: I would consider using '!=='. What you have should work, but the concept of truth and implicit type conversion in js can be quite confusing.

Comment: @Mads Ravn - I agree with !== especially when comparing to 0 - but I never go too far down "JSLint" territory when talking about other people's code as you just never know where they decide to do blah = "1"; if (blah !== 1)...

Comment: @Fenton - Can I write my own javascript code instead of this confirmation box.

Comment: Any specific method to use only on browser or tab close action rather than using on navigation ?