# Javascript register window/tab closing event before window/tab close

Tags: javascript, window

This has / may have been asked before, but, as far as I remember, the question was not satisfactory answered at that time ^^

How can I register a window or tab closing event with Javascript? I have tried body.onclose and body.onunload, and dozens others whose names I made up myself and thought they might possibly exist, but none of it worked, or, if it did, it only fired *after* the window or tab has been closed.

Question:
Is there *any* way to register such an event *before* the window or tab has been closed? It needn't even be compatible with *all* browsers, as long as it works with Firefox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confirm box before closing a tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452963/confirm-box-before-closing-a-tab)

Comment: @CiroSantilli: No, it's not. That other question is about issues with using `onbeforeunload` correctly

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)`= …;`.

Answer (score 8):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var e = e || window.event;

  // For IE and Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Any string';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'Any string';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

WE don't have Onclose but we have OnbeforeUnload. Even I am looking for same event but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Unload and beforeUnload have negative effects on the "page cache" (also known as the "back forward cache").  This is a special cache that preserves some extra state when you navigate away from the page, so that it can be seamlessly resotred when you navigate 'back' (or unclose a tab).  If you've ever wondered why some form fields keep their contents when you click back and some don't - this is often part of the reason.

You should probably take a look at the "pageshow" and "pagehide" events in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_firefox_1.5_caching) and 
[WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/blog/516/webkit-page-cache-ii-the-unload-event/).  IE doesn't have a page cache equivalent, so in that environment you should be fine to use before/unload.  Despite [Opera's early concerns](http://my.opera.com/hallvors/blog/2007/03/14/firefoxs-pageshow-and-pagehide-events-not-dom2-events-compatible), pageshow and pagehide made it into the [HTML5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#event-definitions)