# How to pop up the browser notification if the web page is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have already created the browser notification for inactive web pages using
$(window).blur(function()
 {
  `enter code here`
});
but I have to know how to write code for closed web page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confirmation before closing of tab/browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311341/confirmation-before-closing-of-tab-browser)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript register window/tab closing event before window/tab close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584124/javascript-register-window-tab-closing-event-before-window-tab-close)