# How can I pass variables to another page using a button?

Tags: javascript, post, get

I have a variable var somewhere along my js program. lets call it 'tempVar'.
I want to pass this variable when the button is being pushed. here is part of my code:

```
var TempVar=9;
<form id="boardButton" action="/test"  >
    <button id="joinBoardButton" >JOIN</button>
</form>
```

how can I pass to the page `test` the content of `Tempvar`?

Comment: There are many things you can call Javascript variables. `var` is not one of them...

Comment: ok so not 'var'... lets call it 'tempVar' I editted the question. 'test' is a file that does some kind of a calculation.

Comment: @lonesomeday actually, if you go `this['var'] = something` it will work, won't it? You'll just have to refer to it in the same way to pull out the variable.

Comment: @Jeff: That's a property; not a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onclick` attribute.  Then once in JavaScript you can then seek out the values you need.  If they are on the page already you can use `document.getElementById(someID)` to get the element, then grab your value that way.

You can also use the `this` keyword to access the DOM element just clicked.  See : [what's “this” in javascript onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925734/whats-this-in-javascript-onclick)

#### EDIT :

As for getting a variable you alreday had, if it has a large scope you can just access it directly.

Another way of doing this, is to save the value you want to re-use in a `hidden` input of your site and re-use when needed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `var` is defined globally (on the window object):

```
<form id="boardButton" action="/test">
    <input type="hidden" name="var"/>
    <button id="joinBoardButton" onclick="this.form.elements['var'].value=window.var">JOIN</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an input hidden value to your form

```
<input id="var" type='hidden' name='country' value=''>
```

Then you can set the value with onclick when you submit the form :

```
<button id="joinBoardButton" onclick="this.document.getElementById('var').value=var" >JOIN</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should submit the form with the TempVar in the query string: **.../test?TempVar=ABC**

```
<script>
    var TempVar = "ABC";

    function setVar() {
        document.getElementById('TempVar').value=TempVar;
    }
</script>


<form id="boardButton" action="/test"  >
    <input type="hidden" id="TempVar" name="TempVar" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" id="joinBoardButton" value="JOIN" onclick="setVar();"/>
</form>
```