# Pass 'this' from one function to another in javascript?

Tags: jquery

```
function removeNewsItem(id,idStamp,obj){
 $('#whiteCover')show();

 $('#contentOfBox').html= ('Are you sure you want ot completely remove this news item?<br/><br/><div style="text-align:center;"><input type="button" class="button blue medium" onclick="removeNewsItemConfirmed(\'' + id + '\',\''+idStamp+'\','+**obj**+')" value="Yes"/> <input type="button" class="button red medium" value="No" onclick="resetContentBox();"/></div>');

 $("#whiteCoverContainer").fadeIn();
}

function removeNewsItemConfirmed(id,idStamp,obj){
   alert(obj);
   $(obj).remove();
   return;
}

<tr><td onclick=removeNewsItem('111','134234',this)></td></tr>
```

When I click on the td with the removeNewsItem on it, i cannot seem to be able to pass the 'this' element on to the next function: After the user clicks, they are shown a message asking to confirm deletion, but when they click it the 'this' is not getting passed properl, or more to the point I can't fihure out how...

Could somebody please help: How can I pass obj onto another inline onclick event like above?

Comment: That's not the proper use of jQuery methods. Do you actually know how to program in JavaScript?

Comment: You forgot the quotes (") and this doesn't represent the HTML string but a dom object. But "this" should be passed properly : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925734/whats-this-in-javascript-onclick

Comment: Yeah, what's with that code. `$('#contentOfBox').html=` ???. Then jquery and `onclick` ??? I think you need to learn proper js first, try with a simpler example, and then come back here with proper code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is in reference to the clicked element. If you add a new element with its own `onclick` handler then `this` will be in reference to that. Not the one that created it.

So this will never work the way you are thinking

```
onclick="removeNewsItemConfirmed(\'' + id + '\',\''+idStamp+'\','+**obj**+')"
```

Instead you need to create a reference that you can keep track of.

```
function removeNewsItem(id,idStamp,obj){
   $(obj).addClass('markedForDeletion');
   $('#whiteCover')show();
   $('#contentOfBox').html= ('Are you sure you want ot completely remove this news item?<br/><br/><div style="text-align:center;"><input type="button" class="button blue medium" onclick="removeNewsItemConfirmed()" value="Yes"/> <input type="button" class="button red medium" value="No" onclick="resetContentBox();"/></div>');

   $("#whiteCoverContainer").fadeIn();
}

function removeNewsItemConfirmed(){
   $('.markedForDeletion').remove();
}
```

Overall there are much better ways to handle all of this, but hopefully this gets you going.

Comment: This is also spot on! I am quite new to jQuery, and to me this looks quite tidy...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you should be using events. If you are using jQuery use `on()` to attach events instead of attributes. [More about `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Using this function instead of onclick will return `this` to your function. As an example:

```
<table>
<tr><td>123</td></tr>
<tr><td>456</td></tr>
</table>
```

And some JS

```
// Will have access to this and has ev which is the event
function removeNewsItem(ev){
   var $this = $(this);
}

$('table').on('click', 'td', removeNewsItem);
```

If you need to attach data values to your table cells you can do that with data attributes and [jQuery's data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: And this looks the tightest still! I am going to have to do some erading to understand it all tho. Thanks a lot! For all you replies :)

Answer (score 1):

Your events could look like this (without changing too much of your existing markup):

```
$(".newsItem").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var idStamp = $(this).attr('idStamp');
    $('#whiteCover')show();  

    $('#contentOfBox').html= ('Are you sure you want ot completely remove this news item?<br/><br/><div style="text-align:center;"><input type="button" class="button blue medium" onclick="removeNewsItemConfirmed(\'' + id + '\',\''+idStamp+'\')" value="Yes"/> <input type="button" class="button red medium" value="No" onclick="resetContentBox();"/></div>'); 

    $("#whiteCoverContainer").fadeIn();  
});

function removeNewsItemConfirmed(id,idStamp){              
   alert(id);              
   $("#"+id).remove();              
   return;              
}
```

Your HTML will then look like this:

```
<tr><td id='111' idStamp='134234' class='newsItem'></td></tr>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's awesome, I had never thought of adding additional attributes to the <td>.