# How can I get the javascript event object inside a event handler?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have a div with onclick param:

```
<div onclick="some_function()"></div>
```

How can I access the event object inside the function? I need it to get event.target

```
function some_function() 
{
event = event || window.event;
var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
//does not work in IE and Firefox, but works in chrome
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the event to get to the target. Beware of target vs currentTarget issues:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

```
   <div onclick="some_function(event)"></div>

   function some_function(event) 
   {
       // event.target is the DOM element that triggered the event
   }
```

Comment: He wants the event object, not the target.

Comment: As I see it..he wants the event to get to the target:)

Comment: `this` is not always the same as `event.target`

Comment: Could you explain? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925734/whats-this-in-javascript-onclick

Comment: When you have elements nested inside the one that has the handler, `this` will always refer to the element with the handler, but `event.target` will refer to the most deeply nested element clicked. `<div onclick="alert(this === event.target);">click here <span>then here</span></div>`

Answer (score 10):

This way:

```
<div onclick="some_function(event)"></div>

function some_function(evt) 
{
    // do something with evt (the event passed in the function call)
}
```

Note that the argument name MUST be `event` in the function call. In the event handler you can use the name you want.

A live example: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/KHyAb/

Answer (score 3):

If we work with event listeners, then you have in 'this' the html element and in 'event' the event object.

```
<a id="mya" href="#">Link</a>
var myA= document.querySelector("#mya");
myA.addEventListener("click", some_function);
function some_funtion() {
  //Here the html element is: this
  //Here the event object is: event
  //event.target is not always equal to this
}
<div id="mydiv">click here <span>then here</span></div>
var myDiv = document.querySelector("#mydiv");
myDiv.addEventListener("click", other_function);
function other_function() {
    alert(this === event.target);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using event and this, both

```js
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", function(event) {

  some_function(event, this);
  
}, false);

function some_function(currentEvent, currentObject) {

  alert("Object is: " + currentObject.nodeName);
  alert("Event is: " + currentEvent.type);
  
};
```

```html
<div>Click Me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div onclick="some_function(this, event)"></div>
function some_function(elem, e) 
{
    //You have both: html element (elem), and object event (e)
    //elem is not always equal to e.target
}

<div onclick="alert(this === event.target);">click here <span>then here</span></div>
```

Comment: This is valid for Inline event handlers, as was asked. But if we work with event listeners, then you have in 'this' the html element and in 'event' the event object.