# Values access in function from HTML table which shows entries from database

Tags: javascript, html, sql

`    
        
        User ID
        Leave Type
        Start Date
        End Date
        Status
        Approve/Reject

```
    </tr>
 <c:forEach var="roww" items="${resultt.rows}">
  <tr>
   <td><c:out value="${roww.uid}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${roww.type}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${roww.stdt}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${roww.enddt}"/></td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Approve" name="app" onclick="approval();" />
       <input type="button" value="Reject" name="rej" onclick="rejection();" />  
       `
```

I want to call a function `approval()` when the Approve button is clicked.
The Function needs to access data values from the row in which it is clicked.
I also need to change the value of Status column in the database for that particular row.

I'm using JSP and MySQL database

Comment: Answer might depend on a) what language you are using to generate this HTML and b) what database you are using.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use jQuery and any of the multiple data table plugins it has, then you'd be able to select it with ease and have several features like loading/sorting/searching built in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding this as a parameter in approval should give you the dom element clicked you can then navigate from there i.e `approval(this);`

[what's "this" in javascript onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925734/whats-this-in-javascript-onclick)

i would recommend using something like jQuery to attach the event listener thou.

[jQuery API click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: I tried using 'this' as a parameter and then using it with functions to calculate row or cell index, so that I know which entry to edit in the database. This is not working out..

Comment: if you just need a unique reference to the data add '${roww.uid}' as a parameter i.e approval(this,'${roww.uid}');

Comment: I passed '${roww.uid}' as a parameter to a function. But its value fails to be even printed through the function. Do I need to apply some sort of a special function to be able to display its value?