# This object "undefined"

Tags: jquery, html, undefined, this

I've tried looking around and can't seem to find the same case so here's my problem:

Can anyone please help me with this simple error. Jquery is not my strongest suite but I feel like this is something small that I'm missing. With the code below I get the error 'undefined'.

html:

```
<a href='#' ><img src= "./images/1.jpg"  width= '200px'  id="2" rel="arm1" onclick = 'test()' /></a>
```

Jquery:

```
function test(){
    alert($(this).html());
};
```

What I want is the HTML code of the img tag being clicked on. Is there another way to do this?

So I've tried the following and it doesn't work as well: I've added the onclick to the ahref tag aswell.(error : undefined) I've tried passing by 'event' as a parameter. (error stating 'event' is not declared) when trying to get its html().

PS I do not want to use the id as a onclick function!

Anyhelp will be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: It means that `test` function is not defined or is not available in global scope.

Comment: The `test()` is called in context of `window` and not of the `img` element, so `this` refers to `window`. Even if it would refer to `img` then `html()` would return the `innerHtml`  of the `img`element which will always be empty.

Comment: @dfsq hmmm well it does pop up the alert statement? So it can pick up test function. Is there another way to retrieve the html of that element?

Comment: @t.niese thanks for clarifying that! As said in my above comment Is there another way to retrieve that clicked element's html?

Comment: From teh top of my head, can't you add `this` as an argument. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925734/whats-this-in-javascript-onclick

Comment: Would event.currentTarget be a decent way to access the target object?

Comment: Also IDs can't start with, or just be a number: http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Comment: Also, there's wide support for the outerHTML property, if you want to try using that.  `element.outerHTML`.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. I'll try a few of the suggested options and report back! @logic-unit - the problem is I'm getting that Id actually from the database hence the number.It's acting as a 'product id'

Comment: @Muppet Try using the data attribute to store that information: data-product-id="2". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, this is how you can get image HTML:

```js
function test(obj) {
    alert($(obj).parent().html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">
    <img src= "http://lorempixel.com/100/100" onclick="test(this)" width="200px" id="2" rel="arm1" />
</a>
```

As you can see you can pass current image object to click handler as `this`. From there you go to parent element (`a`) and read its HTML content, which is going to be an image HTML.

**UPD.** t.niese in comments have a point about `outerHTML`, which has good support so the ideal code will look like:

```
alert(obj.outerHTML);
```

Comment: As `outerHTML`  is supported since FF 11 I would use `$(obj)[0].outerHTML` as it would also work if `a` not only contains the `img`

Comment: @t.niese why not `obj.outerHTML`?

Comment: @t.niese Ha! I always thought, that `outerHTML` is not well supported in IE. I was wrong. Thank you, of course `outerHTML` must be used here.

Comment: @caeth yes you are definitely right. It was a long day :D

Comment: Thanks everyone - I didn't actually know about the outerHTML! I've tried the .child() route via the anchor tag but I couldn't get it to work.  But thanks you've all helped ALOT!

Answer (score 1):

`this` in your `test()` function refers to `Window`. To access the clicked element, try this:

HTML:

```
<element onclick='test(this)' />
```

JS:

```
function test(element){
    alert(element.innerHTML);
};
```

though clicking an `<img>` will not show you anything as its innerHTML will be empty.

Edit: As dsfq said, `alert(element.outerHTML)` will show you the HTML of your image.

Comment: In this specific case `element.parentNode.innerHTML` will do the trick though. And of course `outerHTML`.

Comment: @dsfq Oh didn't really read the question, just looked as his `.html()`+1