# a tag's href javascript function, how to reference the caller tag

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

So, i know it is not the best of practices to use `<a href="javascript: foo()">` and pls don't bash me for it. It is at the moment the best solution for an issue I have.

I am editing a website with a bunch of non-interactive elements such as `div` and `spans` which represent menus, drop-downs, buttons and so on. And onto the stage walks **accessibility** in all it's glorious hell raising issues.

So to solve it:

```
<div class="btn" onclick="foo()"> EDIT </div>
<!--had to become-->
<a href="javascript: foo();"><div class="btn">EDIT</div>
```

Now this obviously raises some issues with event targeting and whatnot, but let's forget those for now, most of the functions invoked from these buttons are actually just AJAX calls for new pages and such.

**The bigger issue is the following:**

How does one access any reference to the `<a>` tag in the `foo()` call? `this` is set to `window` and `event` is `undefined`. I tried passing `event` into the brackets like so:

`<a href="javascript: foo(event)">`

Still didn't work. So is there a way to access a reference to the `<a>` tag that invoked the function within the function itself?

**EDIT to clarify why it is not a duplicate:**

This question has nothing to do with `this` in an `onclick`. It has to do with getting a reference without using the `onclick` and instead using `href="javascript: foo()"` which is not the same as using onclick.

Comment: Why don't use keep the `onclick` attribute ? `<a onclick="foo(this)"><div class="btn">EDIT</div></a>`

Comment: @Zenoo will onclick trigger on press of an enter key?

Comment: @Zenoo — So it is an interactive control, which can be activated with the enter key.

Comment: @Liam — No. The question is not about `onclick`.

Comment: @Liam i mean its anything but a duplicate of of that thread

Comment: @Quentin I tested, it does trigger the `onclick` functions, does this mean it fires a `click` event and will triggere both the `onclick` handlers and the ones added via `addEventListener('click')` ?

Comment: "And onto the stage walks accessibility in all it's glorious hell raising issues." — You'd probably be better off solving them with liberal applications of `tabindex` and `aria-role`.

Comment: @Quentin then this will be the way to solve it. As for your last suggestion, i did try the liberal use of said attributes, but they also need to be accompanied by a bunch of `addEventListeners('keypress' function(e){e.keyCode == 13 && e.currentTarget.click();}` handlers to trigger "clicks" on pressing "enter" on div's once they get focused by tabs which makes it a pain

Comment: @Dellirium what? It's basically pass `this`. As detailed in [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/925742/542251), [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51037758/a-tags-href-javascript-function-how-to-reference-the-caller-tag?noredirect=1#comment89067016_51037758) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51037941/542251).

Comment: @Liam it most certinly is not. It is "I am removing onclick, moving a function reference to a wrapper A tag's href. How to access the a tag or event in a function call where event is undefined". This is defined, as a window, which is to be expected. Event on the other hand is undefined, which poses an issue. Event is always defined on regular button click functions, here it is not.

Comment: @Liam the duplicate post is incorrect, the comment here as well as the answer solve the issue I have, however they are not the answer to the question posted. I am thankful to Zenoo and Quentin for helping me get past this issue, the question however still remains and it is how to reference either the element or the event (which would be then used to reference the element) from a `href=" javascript: foo()"` call. You can try and see for yourself that it is not the same as doing it on an `onclick`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply keep the `onclick` attribute on an `<a>` tag :

```
<a onclick="foo(this)"><div class="btn">EDIT</div></a>
```

Calling a Javascript function through an `href` attribute doesn't pass the `click` event alongside it.

So no, you can't access the `event` through a `href` attribute Javascript function call.

Comment: It solves my issue, does not answer the question though. So I am torn on weather to mark it as accepted or not.

Comment: I'm only posting an answer to this because you requested it in the comments. You could also just delete your question, since I don't think anything can be gained from it.

Comment: question still remains unanswered, is it possible to gain references to the `event` or `tag` that the function originated from when using `href`. I am assuming it is not possible since no event gets `fired` probably

Comment: @Dellirium I edited my answer to include this. The click event is still fired, but it's not linked to your function call, so no, it is indeed not possible.