# Click a data from database, then copy the value to text box

Tags: javascript, html

So, I load the data from the database. Then when I click the data, I want the value of the textbox automatically changed into what I clicked. But it seems like it only applies to the first data,and when I click the 2nd or 3rd data, the textbox still show the first data

```php
//the data that covered by <a> as clickable
<?php foreach ($getData as $key): ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#!" onclick="myFunction()"><p id="getid"><?php echo $key->id; ?></p></a>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $key->name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $key->job; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>

//the textbox
<input id="code" type="text" name="id" required>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("code").value = document.getElementById("getid").innerHTML;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the 2nd and 3rd data in your posted question?

Comment: i'm using ```foreach``` to get the data so its looping. let me edit my post to be clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you use the same id *getid* everytime, hence your function cannot know which element you are talking about (in fact a valid html document SHOULD contain each id only once). There a lot of great solutions to this problem. Here is an approach I like:

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = el.innerText
}
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
<table id="table">
<tr><td><a href="#" onclick="myFunction(this)"><p>1</p></a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="#" onclick="myFunction(this)"><p>2</p></a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="#" onclick="myFunction(this)"><p>3</p></a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="#" onclick="myFunction(this)"><p>4</p></a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="#" onclick="myFunction(this)"><p>5</p></a></td></tr>
</table>
```

[Referencing current element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/925742/6320039) in the function allows me to get proper element's text.

Not that I prefered `innerText` over `innerHTML` because the latter doesn't seem necessary, and the former is safer, preventing sql injection attacks.

Comment: If it was useful to you, you can upvote, or even [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/366929) if it is the one you ended up using.

Comment: so that's how i close the case? I'm new here so i don't know that, thank's again :)

Comment: Exactly! You can read the link I shared in my previous comment as well, it is a thorough answer about how to handle answers

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using `id` in an inappropriate way - there should be only one unique id on page.
Since you are printing `<p id="getid"><?php echo $key->id; ?></p>` in a loop it will render element with id `getid` multiple times.

In the script you are using `getElementById("getid")` and it will take the first instance of an element with id `getid` hence you are always getting content of the first element.

The most appropriate way yould be to pass element to the function and get the content in there, like:

```
...
<a href="#!" onclick="myFunction(this)"><p><?php echo $key->id; ?></p></a>
...
function myFunction(el) {
  document.getElementById("code").value = el.innerText;
}
```