# Owl Carousel 2 remove specific item

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I use Owl Carousel 2 and my HTML code is as following. Each image will have a small "x" icon at the upper right corner, when clicked I want the image to be removed from the carousel.

When clicking on the first time, it works well, because the index passed to the "remove_image" function is correct. But on a second click on another image, the index will not be correct anymore.

For example:
1st click on image2.jpg, the index passed to "remove_image" is 1, this is correct. Image properly removed from Owl Carousel 2.

2nd click on image4.jpg, the index passed to "remove_image" is 3. this index is wrong. This is because Owl Carousel 2 has been updated after the image2 was removed. The correct index for image4.jpg now is 2.

How can I fix this problem? Please help. Thanks.

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><img src="/image1.jpg" /><a onclick="remove_image(0);"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="/image2.jpg" /><a onclick="remove_image(1);"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="/image3.jpg" /><a onclick="remove_image(2);"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="/image4.jpg" /><a onclick="remove_image(3);"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="/image5.jpg" /><a onclick="remove_image(4);"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="/image6.jpg" /><a onclick="remove_image(5);"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></div>
</div>
```

```
function remove_image(index) {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('remove', index).owlCarousel('update');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use fixed indexes in your calls to `remove_image`. Since these aren't updated as items are removed, those fixed indexes become inaccurate.

A quick (but not necessarily the best) fix would be to use `this`, instead of fixed indexes, to pass in the anchor elements themselves and then have your function derive the target index from that:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><img src="/image1.jpg" /><a onclick="remove_image(this);"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></div>
    <!-- more slides -->
</div>
```

```
function remove_image(trigger) {
    var $item = $(trigger).closest('.owl-item');
    var index = $item.closest('.owl-stage').children().index($item);
    $item.closest('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('remove', index).owlCarousel('update');
}
```

`.owl-stage` and `.owl-item` are some of several elements that are added when owl carousel is initialized. `.owl-stage` sits between the user-provided container and items, wrapping those items. `.owl-item` wraps each item and are children of `.owl-stage`.

References:

- [`this` in the context of event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925734/whats-this-in-javascript-onclick)
- [jQuery's `.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)
- [jQuery's `.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: I have tried your method. But, I always get -1 for index, for which ever image I click on.

Comment: @JK I had neglected to take into account the modifications owl carousel makes to the user-provided carousel. This has been corrected.

Comment: This method works but unfortunately for dots = true the dots are not updated if some items are deleted

Comment: @AlauddinAfifCassandra As that's a bug with owl carousel, it should be reported on [Owl Carousel's issue tracker](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues).

Comment: @Ouroborus thanks brother for your code above. now it's working when i add .owlCarousel('refresh')