# How to use 'this' in click handers?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an expanding box by clicking on `<a>` but I can't understand how to use the `this`
this is how far I've gotten so far

```js
function change()
{
 if(this.parentElement.style.height!="auto")
 {
  this.parentElement.style.height="auto";
  this.innerText="show less";
  }
  else
  {
  this.parentElement.style.height="100px";
  this.innerText="show lmore";
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;

  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1rem;

  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;


}


.content {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  <a class="read_more" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="change()" style="background-color:yellow; width:50%">show</a>
</div>
```

While you're at it can you remind me why clicking anywhere in the green box is causing the link to be pressed?
 (I can't seem to remember)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's "this" in JavaScript onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925734/whats-this-in-javascript-onclick)

Comment: You should really be using a button here. Anchors are for navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `onclick=change(this)`, then add a parameter to the function instead of using `this` in the function.

```js
function change(el) {
  if (el.parentElement.style.height != "auto") {
    el.parentElement.style.height = "auto";
    el.innerText = "show less";
  } else {
    el.parentElement.style.height = "100px";
    el.innerText = "show lmore";
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  <a class="read_more" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="change(this)" style="background-color:yellow; width:50%">show</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The immediate answer is to pass `this` as an argument into your callback function, but...

**You shouldn't be using an `<a>` element for this in the first place.**

- Anchors are for navigation and not just so that users have something
  to click on. Using them as JavaScript "hooks" can cause accessibility
  issues.
- Any visible HTML element supports a `click` event, so for    inline
  content, just use a `span` instead.
- This will have the added  benefits of you never having to use
  `javascript:void()` again! **And, `this` in a DOM element event
  handler will work without having to pass it into the callback.**

**Next, [do not use inline HTML event attributes like `onclick`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991).**

- This is a 25+ year old technique that simply will not die the death
  it deserves because it's so widely used and copied without an
  understanding of its drawbacks and the benefits of the modern
  approach of using [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in separated JavaScript.

**Strive to remove as many inline styles as possible and use CSS classes.**

- Inline styles have the highest [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and therefore are the
  hardest styles to override if needed.
- Using CSS classes avoids duplication of code, it declutters the HTML,
  and makes adding/removing the class very simple through JavaScript.
- **As you'll see below, relying on CSS classes reduces your JavaScript
  to just two lines in the function!**

```js
// If you set up your events in JavaScript with .addEventListener, "this" just works!
document.querySelector(".read_more").addEventListener("click", change);

function change() {
 // Just toggle the use of the smallSize CSS class and your done!
 this.parentElement.classList.toggle("smallSize");
 
 // And set the show message accordingly
 this.textContent = this.textContent === "Show More" ? "Show Less" : "Show More";
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1rem;
  background-color: #866;
}

.content { overflow: hidden; }

.read_more {
  background-color:yellow; width:50%; cursor:pointer;
}

/* All you need to do is apply this to the parent in the HTML
   and then toggle its use when the show is clicked. */
.smallSize { height:100px; overflow:hidden; }
```

```html
<div class="container smallSize">
  <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  <!-- See how much cleaner the HTML is now? -->
  <span class="read_more">Show More</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parameter in the function like Barmar's answer, but if you really want to use the `this` context, you'll need to attach your click event handler through JavaScript.

When using the inline `onclick="..."` attribute, the `this` context in the function will refer to the overall `window` object instead of the link in question.

```js
var readMoreLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".read_more");
readMoreLinks.forEach(link => link.addEventListener("click", change));

function change()
{
 if(this.parentElement.style.height!="auto")
 {
  this.parentElement.style.height="auto";
  this.innerText="show less";
  }
  else
  {
  this.parentElement.style.height="100px";
  this.innerText="show lmore";
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;

  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1rem;

  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;


}


.content {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  <a class="read_more" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background-color:yellow; width:50%">show</a>
</div>
```

Comment: But you really should use `.addEventListener()` instead of event properties.