# Get cell Value of Table html

Tags: javascript, html-table, rows

I have this code (opt1) to get the text of the cell, which is clicked, but this alerts **all of the objects in the table** as its in a loop. But when I place it outside the loop I just get a random text from the table and not the one which is clicked (opt2).

I need the textContent of the cell, which is clicked, once, and not any other.

FYI: the cell contains multiple `<td>` inside `<tr>`.

The current method gets me the name text either of all cells (opt1) or the last cell (opt2)

HTML:

```
<table id="table">

        <tr class="cell" onclick="RowHandlers()">
            <td class="name">Name</td>
            <td class="date">Date</td>
            <td class="subject">Subject</td>

        </tr>

    </table>
```

**opt1**

```
function RowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var name;
    for (var i=1;i<table.rows.length;i++) {

        name = table.rows[i].cells[0].innerText;

        alert(name);
    }
   
}
```

**opt2**

```
function RowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var name;
    for (var i=1;i<table.rows.length;i++) {

        name = table.rows[i].cells[0].innerText;

       
    }
    alert(name);
}
```

Comment: There are basically two types data in your setup, text content which is the text in the `<td>` or anything between the tags of an element ex.`<div>`text`</div>`, `<span>`text`</span>` and then there's `.value` `<input value='text'>`. ATM your code is trying to get the former whilst you probably want the latter. If you want a definitive answer, please provide the HTML and state exactly what data you want, the former, the latter, or both?

Comment: You mentioned there were text elements as in `<input>`s?

Comment: @nertz Why can you not use the first cell? What is different about it? Can you please provide _all_ the relevant HTML?

Comment: @nertz it sounds like you are intentionally changing your criteria slightly each time I have adjusted my answer. There would be a point when someone that earnestly sought out an answer would've gotten there by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be identifying the clicked row after a click has happened.

We can solve this in multiple ways:

1. In JS, use the [event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)'s [`target` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target):

   1. (**Preferred**) Add handler via [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

      1. Use a single handler by making use of [event propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#example_5_event_propagation).
      2. Add handlers to each row.
   2. (Discouraged) Add handler via `onevent` property. Only one handler can be added this way.
   3. (Deprecated) Use the global object [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event).
2. (Discouraged) In HTML, use [inline event `onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) on each row:

   1. Pass `this` to the handler function (e.g. `<tr onclick="RowHandler(this)">`). [`this` in inline events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/925742/13561410) will refer to the clicked element.
   2. Add IDs to each row (e.g. `<tr id="row1">`). For each row, pass its ID to the function (e.g. `onclick="RowHandler('row1')"`). Search for the element by the passed ID.

## Using `addEventListener()`

To add a listener, pass the event type and the listener:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event) {
  console.log(input.value);
  input.value = "";
}
```

```html
<input><button>Click me!</button>
```

### Event propagation

Because events bubble up the DOM, `<table>`'s listener will also fire when its rows are clicked. We can use `event.target` to get the event's origin element and find the clicked row:

```js
const table = document.querySelector("table");
table.addEventListener("click", tableClickHandler);

function tableClickHandler(event) {
  const row = event.target.closest("tr.cell"); // event.target may be a <td>
  
  const isInRow = Boolean(row);
  const isFirstRow = row === table.rows[0];
  if (!isInRow || isFirstRow) return;
  
  const name = row.cells[0].textContent;
  const date = row.cells[1].textContent;
  const subject = row.cells[2].textContent;
  
  console.log("Clicked:", { name, date, subject });
}
```

```css
table,td{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cell">
    <td class="name">Some name</td>
    <td class="date">01-01-1999</td>
    <td class="subject">Some subject</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cell">
    <td class="name">Another name</td>
    <td class="date">02-02-2020</td>
    <td class="subject">Another subject</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## Regarding your solutions

You are missing some way of identifying the clicked element; see my suggestions above.

In **opt2**, you are looping through all rows, but constantly overriding the variable `name` before using it. Therefore it is the same as only reading the name of the last row.

You may want to use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) over [`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText), because [it doesn't cause a reflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext). If visibility of the content matters, choose `.innerText`, otherwise `.textContent`.

A table usually consists of sections (e.g. `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>`, or an implicit section). Each section consists of rows; each row consists of cells. Therefore, your class name `"cell"` for a row may be confused with actual table cells (`<td>`/`<th>`).

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```js
const [row] = document.getElementsByClassName('cell');
row.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.innerText);
})
```

```html
<table id="table">

        <tr class="cell">
            <td class="name">Name</td>
            <td class="date">Date</td>
            <td class="subject">Subject</td>

        </tr>

    </table>
```